# From MYSQL query to google charts

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

Let me start by saying, i'm not sure how to ask the right question on this, but here goes...

I have a database of amounts that all have times attached to them. for example four rows would look like:

```
2  | 1000 | 2012-11-01 12:09:09
2  | 800  | 2012-11-01 12:10:21
10 | 900  | 2012-11-01 12:11:36
10 | 750  | 2012-11-01 12:12:46
```

The first column is the user. I am wanting to out put this to a google line graph, but really struggling on how to set-up the query.

The end result in the javascript array needs to looks like:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'User 2');
data.addColumn('number', 'User 10');

data.addRows([
    ['12:09', 1000, null],
    ['12:10', 800, null],
    ['12:11', 800, 900],
    ['12:12', 800, 750]
]);
```

Any help or steers more than welcome on this. I'm thinking a few php loop, but a little stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Put this at top of Your document:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=myDbName;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbUserName';
$password = 'dbPassword';

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $name);

$result = $pdo->query('select * from YourAmountsTableName');
foreach ($result as $row) {

$rows[] = "['{$row['time']}',{$row['ammount']},{$row['yourThirdValue']}]";

}
$rowsString = implode(',',$rows);
?>
```

Now In Your HTML document, or Your Javascript, echo the $rowsString in the place for rows:

```
data.addRows([<?php echo $rowsString; ?>]);
```

adjust the code given for names, passwords ect. I have not tested the code, so please check if no quotes are missing or other misspellings. As for the Google Chart,
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples?hl=pl
have great examples

Comment: Thanks for the response PiotrN, one thing i maybe should have mentioned it there could be 1 user or 1000 users, this isn't fixed at just two. So the columns aren't fixed. Also there isn't a third amount, this is taken from the next row in the DB.

Comment: It will merge as many results as You want, it't not limited to just 2. Users are in rows, not collumns, or am I missing something ?

If You need to aggregate user data, do that in SQL, same for merging column from other table.

Comment: The users are needed to be in columns for google charts to work. It would be nice and easy if each row followed the line. for a row would be ['date', 'user1 amount', 'user2 amount']